# ruby on android : ruboto vs rhodes?

Tags: android, jruby, rhodes, ruboto, mirah

Has anyone tried developing an Android app using Ruby? If so, which tool would you recommend? 
What are the advantages and disadvantages, comparing (between) both?

Any sharing of experience, insight, etc., would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Disclamer: I haven't used this project at all. Having said that:

The [**Mirah**](http://www.mirah.org/) [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirah_(programming_language))'s syntax is based heavily on Ruby and it compiles to Java byte code which you could then run through the [dx](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#dx) android tool.

Another option to consider would be [**JRuby**](http://jruby.org/). JRuby is a fairly mature implementation of Ruby which, I believe, [supports ahead of time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby#Performance).

Answer (score 4):

[Rhodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_Framework) uses compiled Ruby 1.9 bytecode at run time, and does not use the Dalvik JVM at all (it's written in C++ with the NDK). Hence, it is much faster than [Ruboto](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto).

Comment: will rhodes generate an android/ios native app? or it only generate a regular web app with HTML5 pages?

Comment: Generates a native Android/iOS app

Comment: Which is easier to use? I haven't found much good documentation/tutorials on either.